# Forcing two separate columns to show up side by side in html

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
            <div class="wrapper-small">

                <div class="column-section spaced-big clearfix">
                    <div class="column one-second align-right">
                        <div class="widget">                            
                            <h5 class="widget-title title-alt"><strong>Row 1</strong></h5>
                            <h5 class="widget-title title-alt"><strong>Row 1</strong></h5>
                            <h5 class="widget-title title-alt"><strong>Row 3</strong></h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column one-second">
                        <div class="widget align-left last-col">
                            <h5 class="">Row 1 info</h5> 
                            <h5 class="">Row 2 info</h5>
                            <h5 class="">Row 3 info</h5>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I load the page in my computer this code does what it's supposed to do: it shows two columns side by side. However, when I load this in a mobile device, the two columns are placed one on top of the other. Is there a way to avoid this without making a table, perhaps using CSS? The problem is that I have about 100 pages with the same code I would need to fix manually if I can't do this simply by using CSS.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read up on [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) if you are unfamiliar with it.

```
.column-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; // Default state
}
```

This will put the two columns side by side.

Comment: But this will affect all other `column-section` div’s correct? I need to only affect this at some places.

Comment: Yes, it will affect all divs with that class name. You may want to give which ever ones you want to adjust a unique class for this property.

Comment: `flex-direction: row` is the default and just redundant but not necessary to use.

Comment: this solution did not work.